# Putting an item in a array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the actors in the array into a table when I add an actor it would show up in the table. For each actor I should be able to update and delete them.

I'm not sure on how to get the values from html to display in the table.

```js
var actors, i;

var Info = [
            {firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Statham", birth: "July 26, 1967", gender: "Male", genre: "Action, Crime, Thriller"}, 
            {firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Wahlberg", birth: "June 5, 1971", gender: "Male", genre: "Action, Comedy, Drama"}
           ];
var displayActors = function(actors) {
    var str = "<table class='table'>";
    str += "<tr>";
    str += "<th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Gender</th><th>Genre</th>";
    str += "</tr>";
    for(i=0; i < actors.length; i++){
        str += "<tr>";
        str += "<td>" + actors[i].firstName + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + actors[i].lastName + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + actors[i].birth + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + actors[i].gender + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + actors[i].genre + "</td>";
        str += "</tr>";
    }
    str += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("actorGrid").innerHTML = str; 
}

window.onload = function() {
    displayActors(Info);
}
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    var fName = "";
 var str = "<table class='table'>";
    fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if(fName != "") {
  str += "<tr>";
  str += "<td>" + Info.push({firstName: fName}) + "</td>";
  str += "</tr>";
    }
    str += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("actorGrid").innerHTML += str;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h2 class="ad">Add Actors</h2>
    <div id="add">
        <label>First Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="fname"/><br />

        <label>Last Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="lname"/><br />

        <label>Date of Birth</label><br />
        <input type="date" id="dob"/><br />

        <form action="">
            <label>Gender:</label><br />
            Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male"/>
            Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female"/><br />
        </form>

        <form action="">
            <label>Genre:</label><br />
            <label>Action<input type="checkbox" id="action"/></label>
            <label>Adventure<input type="checkbox" id="adventure"/></label>
            <label>Thriller<input type="checkbox" id="thriller"/></label>
            <label>Drama<input type="checkbox" id="drama"/></label>
        </form>
                   
            <br /><input type="button" id="submit" value="Add Actor" />
            <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="actorGrid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the specific issue with your code? What part should we look at?

Comment: @FelixKling I believe the author specifies that in the description. "I'm not sure on how to get the values from html to display in the table."

Comment: I advice you to use a javascript library or framework like jQuery, AngularJS or Vue.js

Comment: @8protons: Yeah, it's not clear to me what exactly that means and whether the posted code is their approach to implement this (and if it is, what exactly is wrong with that code) or just some code that is somehow related (and if so, how?)

Comment: If `Info.push({firstName: fName})` is the issue, note that `push` returns the new length of the array. You probably want to factor out the row generation code into it's own function and simply call it with the new values from the form. Or add the new object to the array and rerender the whole table: `Info.push({firstName: fName}); displayActors(Info);`.

Comment: `Info.push({firstName: fName})` is not putting it into the array

Comment: *"`Info.push({firstName: fName})` is not putting it into the array"* it definitely is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with rerendering the whole table, then I believe your click event handler can just be

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  Info.push({firstName: fName});
  displayActors(Info);
};
```

With regard to your questions, `Array#push` is exactly how you can add a new value to an array and the `value` property is exactly how you read values from form elements.

Comment: this was exactly what i needed, now can i do this with the other fields that i have such as the radio buttons, date picker, and check boxes?

Comment: Of course. Get all those values, create a single object and add it to the array.

Comment: how do I add all info to the same row

Comment: Just add more properties to the object. Exactly like the preexisting objects in your example.

Comment: You do exactly the same what you did with `fname`, but for the other fields: `var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value; var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value; /* ... */ Info.push({firstName: fName, lastName: lName, /* .... */});`.

Comment: that's exactly what i did but each item gets added to a different row

Comment: Then you are adding multiple objects, not a single object as I am suggesting. `displayActor` creates a new row for every object. Hence you must be adding multiple objects if every piece of data is in its own row. I get the impression that you haven't actually written the code that renders the table yourself? Because if you did it should be obvious to you what the issue is. If you didn't you really just spend some time trying to understand what it does.